# Using page object for selenium, where is the best place to initiate the browser and get url?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

I m using pytest with selenium and have started to refactor the tests to use page object model.  I have read up on some examples from books and blogs.  They call webdriver.firefox()   at different places for the tests,  for example:

1. It is in base page class init
   Or
2. Having a fixture in the test class that called an instance of the base page and then the driver in the fixture itself
   Or
3. From a class in conftest.py

Is there a best practice way to determine where the browser should be started?